# Remove an element from a linked list in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to learn C++ right now because of a class I'm going to have to take, and am coming from Java. I'm currently going through the book "Jumping into C++" and completing the exercises. After reading the section on linked lists, it tells me to create my own linked list and have a method that will remove an element (using pointers in the exercise).

So far I've been able to add values to my linked list, and display my linked linked list. After doing my remove element method, and having my program explicitly tell me it has deleted the value at a specific memory address, I display the list again to find that my value still somehow appears at the memory address that has supposedly been deleted.

This is my removeElement method:

```
// remove an element from the linked list
void removeElement(int remValue) {
    // to remove an element, we go through the list, find the value given
    // if we find it, stop
    // to remove, disconnect the link
    // relink the two values now (ie. value 1->2->3->NULL, 2 is removed, 1->3->NULL )
    LinkedList* current = head;
    LinkedList* next = current;
    while(current != NULL) {
        if(current->value == remValue) { // if match
            break; // break out of while
        }
        else {
            cout << "Value " << current->value << " does not match " << remValue << ".\n";
            next = current; // save in case
            current = current->pNextValue; // go to next value
        }
    } // end while
    if(current == NULL) { // if we reached end of list
        cout << "Can't remove value: no match found.\n"; // no match, cant remove
    } else { // found match
        cout << "Deleting: " << current << "\n";
        delete current;
        current = next->pNextValue; // current is updated
    }
}
```

Here is my entire code for the linked list(including some tests to see where stuff is going):

http://pastebin.com/cHZr4cBa

I realize that most of my code is not efficient and not normal for a realistic linked list, I'm just trying to figure out pointers and how to use them in a linked list at the most basic level.

Comment: As a side note, in modern C++, you don't really need `delete` (and in C++14 not really `new` either), so you might want to find more modern C++ learning material...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't actually *unlink* the node you remove.

You need to keep track of the *previous* node, and make its `next` pointer point to the current nodes `next` node. Also think of the special case when the node to remove is the first node.

Answer (score 2):

@Joachim Pileborg is right, you need to record previous node, not `next`.

try this code:

```
// remove an element from the linked list
void removeElement(int remValue) {
    LinkedList* prev = head; // empty header
    LinkedList* current = head->pNextValue; // the first valid node
    while(current != NULL) {
        if(current->value == remValue) { 
            break; 
        }
        else {
            cout << "Value " << current->value << " does not match " << remValue << ".\n";
            prev = current; 
            current = current->pNextValue; // go to next value
        }
    }
    if(current == NULL) { // if we reached end of list or the list is empty
        cout << "Can't remove value: no match found.\n"; 
    } else {
        cout << "Deleting: " << current << "\n";
        prev->pNextValue = current->pNextValue; // unlink the node you remove
        delete current; // delete the node
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the links in your list to remove the node that you deleted.

Note that using the `delete` operator does not change any values in memory. It simply tells the operating system that you are no longer using that location in memory and it can reclaim it for other uses.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node* next;
    int data;
    Node();
    ~Node();
    void print();
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    int length;
    Node* head;

    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void add(int data);
    void remove(int data);
    Node* search(int data);
    void print();
    void size();
};

Node::Node(){
    //set default values;
}

Node::~Node(){
    cout << "NODE DELETED" <<endl;
}

void Node::print(){
    Node* node = this;
    if(node != NULL){
        cout << "===============================" << endl;
        cout << this->data << endl;
        cout << "===============================" << endl;
    }
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    this->length = 0;
    this->head = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){
    cout << "LIST DELETED" <<endl;
}

void LinkedList::add(int data){
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->data = data;
    node->next = this->head;
    this->head = node;
    this->length++;
}

void LinkedList::remove(int data){
    if(this->length == 0){
        cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
    }else if(this->head->data == data){
        Node* current = head;
        this->head = this->head->next;
        delete current;
        this->length--;
    }else{
        Node* previous = this->head;
        Node* current = head->next;
        while(current != NULL) {
            if(current->data == data) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        if(current == NULL) {
            cout << "Can't remove value: no match found.\n";
        } else {
            previous->next = current->next;
            delete current;
            this->length--;
        }
    }
}

Node* LinkedList::search(int data) {
    Node* head = this->head;
    while(head){
        if(head->data == data){
            return head;
        }else{
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    cout << "No match found.\n";
    return NULL;
}

void LinkedList::print(){
    if(this->length == 0){
        cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
    }else{
        Node* head = this->head;
        int i = 1;
        cout << "===============================" << endl;
        while(head){
            cout << i << ": " << head->data << endl;
            head = head->next;
            i++;
        }
        cout << "===============================" << endl;
    }
}

void LinkedList::size(){
    cout << "List Length: " << this->length << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 3){
            list->add(105);
            list->add(106);
        }
        list->add(rand() % 100);
    }

    list->print();
    list->size();

    list->remove(105);

    list->print();
    list->size();

    Node* node = list->search(106);
    node->print();

    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code base on [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)'s answer.

```cpp
void removeElement(int remValue) {
    LinkedList * current, next, previous;
    current = *&head;
    
    while(current != NULL){

        // `next` node
        next = current->next;

        // if match
        if(current->value == remValue){

            // if `previous` and `next` has a node, link the `previous` node to `next` node
            if(previous != NULL && next != NULL) previous->next = next; 

            // if `current` is the last node, link `previous` node to `NULL`
            else if(previous != NULL && next == NULL) previous->next = NULL;

            // if `current` node is the first node, set the header node to `next` node
            else if(previous == NULL && next != NULL) *&head = next;
            
            // if `current` node is the only item, empty the list
            else *&head = NULL;

            cout << "Deleting: " << current->value << "\n";

            // delete node
            delete current;

            // exit the function
            return;
        
        // if not match
        } else cout << "Value " << current->value << " does not match " << remValue << ".\n";
        

        // Variables for next loop
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    // No Match
    cout << "Can't remove value: no match found.\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// C++ program to delete a node in

// singly linked list recursively

 

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std; 

 

struct node { 

    int info; 

    node* link = NULL; 

    node() {} 

    node(int a) 

        : info(a) 

    { 

    } 

};

 

/*

Deletes the node containing 'info' part as val and

alter the head of the linked list (recursive method)

*/

void deleteNode(node*& head, int val) 

{

     

    // Check if list is empty or we 

    // reach at the end of the 

    // list. 

    if (head == NULL) { 

        cout << "Element not present in the list\n"; 

        return; 

    } 

    // If current node is the node to be deleted 

    if (head->info == val) { 

        node* t = head; 

        head = head->link; // If it's start of the node head 

                           // node points to second node 

        delete (t); // Else changes previous node's link to 

                    // current node's link 

        return; 

    } 

    deleteNode(head->link, val); 

}

 

// Utility function to add a 

// node in the linked list

// Here we are passing head by 

// reference thus no need to

// return it to the main function

void push(node*& head, int data) 

{

    node* newNode = new node(data); 

    newNode->link = head; 

    head = newNode; 

}

 

// Utility function to print 

// the linked list (recursive

// method)

void print(node* head) 

{

     

    // cout<<endl gets implicitly 

    // typecasted to bool value 

    // 'true' 

    if (head == NULL and cout << endl) 

        return; 

    cout << head->info << ' '; 

    print(head->link); 

}

 

int main() 

{

    // Starting with an empty linked list 

    node* head = NULL;
```

Comment: The `main` is missing/incomplete! And please use Stackoverflow's Markdown when inserting code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code