# How do i delete any item from a linked list?

Tags: struct, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function that deletes an element at a given position from a linked list, for now im using a linked list with only a head pointer. Now it may be that the user inputs a position that is larger than the size of the linked list so to remedy that i wrote this:

```
int delete(struct node** head, int pos)
{
    struct node* temp = *head;
    while(pos!=0 && temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        pos--;
    }
    if(pos>0)
        return 0;

}
```

but it gives the following error

```
fish: './a.out' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

i tried to debug it by writing a new code

```
int delete(struct node** head)
{
    if((*head)->next==NULL)
    return 1;
}
```

but it gives the same error

Comment: Thought experiment time: what happens if `*head` is NULL?

Comment: @paddy oh right! thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599343/remove-an-element-from-a-linked-list-in-c/51127711 maybie this can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `head` is `NULL` the evaluation of `temp->next` will give undefined behaviour or the error as you experienced.

However, there is more to correct to your function.

- There is no deletion happening. To delete a node, its predecessor should have its `next` property update to point to the node after the removed node. The removed node should then be freed.
- The value of `*head` should be modified when the *first* node of the list is removed.
- The function should return an `int`, and so also when the deletion was successful (and `pos == 0` after the loop), there should be a `return` that is executed, probably returning 1 to indicate success.
- Not a problem, but I would advise using a different name for your function. If ever you move to C++, then `delete` will be a reserved word.

So:

```
int removeNode(struct node** head, int pos) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    struct node* temp = *head;
    if (pos == 0) { // Case where first node must be removed
        *head = (*head)->next; // Modify head reference
        free(temp);
        return 1; // Indicate success
    }

    while (pos > 1 && temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        pos--;
    }
    if (pos != 1 || temp->next == NULL) {
        return 0; // Invalid position
    }
    //  Remove the node
    struct node* prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return 1; // Indicate success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @paddy commented,

i didn't consider the case where head itself is pointing to NULL.

a simple if statement solved it

```
struct node* temp = *head;
    if(temp==NULL){
        printf("Empty LL\n");
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
```